# Is there an string equivalent to LPTSTR?

Tags: c++, windows, stdstring

Is there an string equivalent to LPTSTR?  I know of string and wstring. Is there a tstring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define one:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> mystring;
...
mystring test = _T("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Would you need to make new traits too?

Comment: AFAIK `TCHAR` is either `char` or `wchar_t`. The standard provides a specialization for both types.

Comment: GMan: tstring becomes an alias for either string or wstring (they are typedefs of basic\_string<char> and basic\_string<wchar\_t>, respectively).

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking completely wrong for a bit. This solution seems rather clean, then. (Just rename it `tstring` and throw it in a namespace :P)

Comment: Hah, oops, I actually read the answer as 'tstring' instead of 'mystring', since that is the common name.

Answer (score 4):

Another option (doesn't require `windows.h`):

```
#if defined(_UNICODE) || defined(UNICODE)
  typedef std::wstring ustring_t;
  typedef wchar_t uchar_t;
  #define TEXT(x) (L##x)
#else
  typedef std::string ustring_t;
  typedef char uchar_t;
  #define TEXT(x) (x)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
ustring_t mystr = TEXT("hello world");
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but without `<windows.h>` you don't have the `TEXT()` macro either.

Comment: Added define for `TEXT` macro.