# Why does GetComputerNameEx return a string with a strange encoding?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a function that returns the name of the computer. This is what I have so far:

```
char* getName()
{
    char buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD length = sizeof(buffer);

    GetComputerNameEx((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)0, buffer, &length);

    return buffer;
}
```

But it doesn't really work. It seems it returns a string with very strange character encoding. I would appreciate all help.

Comment: `char buffer[...]` is only valid within the scope of your function!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 5):

Use an `std::string` to avoid memory issues. And as `std::string` uses single byte characters, you should use the single-byte version of `GetComputerNameEx`, `GetComputerNameExA`.

Also it is a good idea to check the error value, as the documentation explicitly states that the computer name might be longer than MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH.

```
std::string getName()
{
    char buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD length = sizeof(buffer);

    bool ok = GetComputerNameExA((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)0, buffer, &length);

    if (ok) { 
        return buffer;
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Or you can use the wide version:

```
std::wstring getName()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD length = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(wchar_t);

    bool ok = GetComputerNameExW((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)0, buffer, &length);

    if (ok) { 
        return buffer;
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

or make a code that works under both environments (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132753/automatically-change-between-stdstring-and-stdwstring-according-to-unicode-s)):

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> getName()
{
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD length = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(TCHAR);

    bool ok = GetComputerNameEx((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)0, buffer, &length);

    if (ok) { 
        return buffer;
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning use of TCHAR. Aside from other errors, the question mentions strange encoding of the returned string, which is most likely to do with building in Unicode.

Comment: Please don't advise the use of `TCHAR` today. That was useful when you needed code to compile under both Win95 and WinNT. No longer is this useful.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's true, especially with the gradual deprecation of MCBS builds in Visual Studio, but using `TCHAR` at least would match the rest of the build. If using VS.

Comment: @icabod The right way to do it is to compile for `UNICODE` and use `wchar_t`, `std::wstring`, `L"..."` etc. Using `TCHAR` just adds a useless and confusing level of indirection.

Comment: In either case, you should pass the final `length` to the string constructor and not rely on the `buffer` being null-terminated, eg: `return std::string(buffer, length);` or `return std::wstring(buffer, length);` or `return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(buffer, length);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau the returned value seems to be null-terminated. Is there any explicit reason for this? (I've read the MSDN page again and what seems to be is even more important is to check the return value to be true)