# Can I use the _T() macro with a variable?

Tags: c++, variables

```
string pagexx = "http://website.com/" + chatname;
string pathxx = "test";
HRESULT resxx = URLDownloadToFile (NULL, _T(pagexx.c_str()),_T(pathxx.c_str()), 0, NULL );
```

The error is "Error: identifier "Lpagexx" is undefined."
and same with pathxx

I cant just enter the string like `_T("nice")` because I need chatname in it specifically. how can I make this work?

Comment: Try `wstring` instead.  Or look up wide character strings vs regular strings.  or turn off Unicode in your complier settings.

Comment: for your next questions I advise you to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) to enable people to help you with your problem

Answer (score 1):

`_T` is a macro for putting the proper prefix on a literal. That is not what you're doing, so you don't want to use `_T`.

Your problem begins on the very first line, since you've hardcoded that you're using strings with narrow characters (i.e. `string` is a string specifically of `char` elements) rather than selecting the appropriate string type. See the question [Automatically change between std::string and std::wstring according to unicode setting in MSVC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132753/automatically-change-between-stdstring-and-stdwstring-according-to-unicode-s).

Answer (score 1):

If your strings only contain non-unicode then your simplest solution is:

```
HRESULT resxx = URLDownloadToFileA (NULL, pagexx.c_str(), pathxx.c_str(), 0, NULL );
```

The `_T` stuff has been obsolete for a decade at least, there is no reason at all to bother with the complication of having an application compile against two different versions of Windows API.

If your `std::string`s contain UTF-8 then you will need to convert them to UTF-16 and then call `URLDownloadToFileW`.

Answer (score 0):

`_T` is just a macro with prefixis its argument with `L` (if compiled with unicode). Variables must be declared using `wchar_t`(or `wstring` and simmilar)

Assuming `chatname` is of type `wstring`.

```
 wstring pagexx = L"http://website.com/" + chatname;
 wstring pathxx = L"test";
 HRESULT resxx = URLDownloadToFile ( NULL, pagexx.c_str(), pathxx.c_str(), 0, NULL );
```

Or better (since you are compiling something under Microsoft, you can use more general macros, so that you can compile same code with or without `UNICODE` being set).

```
 _tstring pagexx = _T("http://website.com/") + chatname;
 _tstring pathxx = _T("test");
 HRESULT resxx = URLDownloadToFile ( NULL, pagexx.c_str(), pathxx.c_str(), 0, NULL );
```

Comment: _tstring is undefined, ahh im such a noob. :(

Comment: ok, turning off Unicode helped me. Thanks

Comment: Your first example wont compile unless you prefix the string literals with a `L`. Your second example needs a `_T()` wrapper around the string literals.